# What does the '$' mean in command line commands?

Tags: command, line

I often find command line commands starting with *dollar signs* in instructions to install many things. For example to install **Ruby** in **Ubuntu**, the website says to use the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

What does the `$` represent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$ is not part of the command, it is just shown to illustrate terminal input. A full log of the guys entry would read something like

```
Dominic@stackoverflow$ sudo ap...
```

See the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/48215530/1117934, for a more complete explanation on the difference between `$` and `#`.

Comment: I see. But why would you include the dollar sign? Is it not a given and included in every command?

Comment: Clarity I guess. Not everybody is familiar with terminal entry and may not immediately recognise where they should be without a prompt.

Answer (score 11):

The `$` is not part of the command. It's there to tell you that this command needs to be executed as a regular user.

When you prompt as a regular user (in bash shell at least), the line starts with the user name you're currently prompt as, followed by `@`, followed by the machine hostname, followed by `:`, followed by the current location, followed by `$`.

It looks like this :

```
bob@work-station:~$
```

But, if you prompt as **root**, the last `$` will be replaced by a `#` :

```
root@work-station:~#
```

And that's the point of those tutorials :

- If the command starts with `$`, you know that the command should be executed as regular user.
- If it starts with `#`, it should be executed as root.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a Command Line Interface (CLI), the dollar sign ($) is typically referred to as a "prompt symbol" or simply a "prompt." It indicates that the CLI is ready to receive input from the user. The specific appearance and behavior of the prompt may vary depending on the operating system and shell being used.

Answer (score 0):

Not all "$" are command prompts though. Take for example:

for filename in *; do
mv "$filename" "AIart_$counter.png"
((counter++))
done